# Pushing an object to an array using a repository

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm new to Aurelia. And I'm browsing to some examples and saw this one.
It has this page that **lists**(`cars.js`) all the cars and has a **create button** that redirects you to a different page where you can enter a new car(`addCar.js`), once you hit save, you'll be redirected to the lists of cars. Simple enough.

My question is, how does the newly added car gets push to the lists of cars? This example uses a repository to abstract all interaction to the api. Do the files share the same instance of `this.cars`?

**dataRepository.js**

```
@inject(HttpClient)
export class DataRepository {
    constructor(httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

getCars() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!this.cars) {
            this.httpClient.fetch('api/Cars')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then( data => {
                this.cars = data;
                resolve(this.cars);
            }).catch(err => reject(err));
        }
        else
            resolve(this.cars);
    });
    return promise;
}

    addCar(car) {
        var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.httpClient.fetch('api/Cars',{
                method: 'POST',
                body: json(car)
            }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.cars.push(data); // <-- here, how does this pass the related data to cars.js?
                resolve(data);
            }).catch(err=>reject(err));
        });
        return promise;
    }
}
```

**addCar.js**

```
@inject(DataRepository)
export class AddCar {
    constructor(dataRepository) {
        this.car = { carType: "Big" };
        this.dataRepository = dataRepository;
    }

    activate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction) {
        this.router = navigationInstruction.router;
    }

    save() {
        this.validation.validate().then(()=>{
            this.dataRepository.addCar(this.car).then(car=> this.router.navigateToRoute('cars'));
        });
    }
}
```

**cars.js**

```
@inject(DataRepository)
export class Cars {
    constructor(dataRepository) {
        this.dataRepository = dataRepository;
    }

    activate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction) {
        this.cars = [];
        this.router = navigationInstruction.router;
        return this.dataRepository.getCars().then(cars => {
            this.cars = cars;
        });
    }

    addCar() {
        this.router.navigateToRoute("addCar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing too much about Aurelia's specifics, I would assume it is using single-instance dependency injection (hence the @inject directive). That instance has the collection of cars and, when passed to the dependent's constructor, is set as an instance member. More info can be found [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/dependency-injection/latest/dependency-injection-basics).

Comment: Yup. Good answer.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question?

Comment: Quick question. If DataRepository contains the lists of cars. Then when its injected. Wont't you be calling the list of cars like this `this.dataRepository.cars`?

Comment: I think ultimately, yes (depending on implementation). The point of the repository pattern is that you do not necessarily know the underlying structure of the data. It might be a list, but it might be a database. In the case of a database, you would not be referencing it as a property.  I would recommend creating the interface of actions you want to expose and not expose the collection directly.